# streaming through gstreamer not displaying in vlc

Tags: network-programming, gstreamer, vlc, libvlc

I have a `raspberry pi` board with camera module on which I have installed `gstreamer` and make it `rtsp server`. Now I successfully stream a `rtp` streaming from that gstreamer.
I am able to receive it on my client machine(window 7) and successfully display on `GOMPLAYER`. But when I receive same streaming on VLC then it show only one frame and that frame remain still.
Now I have no idea what is happening with me. and why only one frame is only display on vlc.
This is the command I am using on pi board to launch gstreamer.

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 720 -w 1280 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -vf -hf -n -o - | gst-launch    
-v fdsrc ! h264parse ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 |   
./test-launch "( tcpclientsrc host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! 
avdec_h264 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

This is the command i am using for vlc on cmd run as administrator

```
vlc.exe rtsp://192.168.1.24:8554/test --extraintf=http: logger --verbose=2 - 
-file-loggeing --logfile=vlc-log3.txt
```

- `192.168.1.24` is static IP of my pi board

I am also post a screen shot:

[image]

I an also attach log file:

[image]

Comment: If anyone have answer of my problem please help

Comment: Are you running any other clients when you connect with VLC? I ask, because if your server is not multicast it may only support one connection at a time.